# List contains in List check

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I have a `IEnumerable<Object> a` with 6 items in chronological order in it.
I want to test if list `IEnumerable<Object> b` with 3 items in chronological order.

`IEnumerable<Object> a` item values: a,b,c,d,f,g

`IEnumerable<Object> b` item values: b,d,f

Is it possible to be done with LINQ ?

Comment: So do you want to check that everything in `b` is also in `a`, or do you _know_ that they will be and only want to check that they are in the right order?

Comment: Do you mean alphabetical instead of chronological order?

Comment: @Rawling, yes I want to check if list a has all items from list b in  the same order

Comment: In the same order - or consecutive (i.e. the same sequence appears in the master list)?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Not sure if you'll see this, but what was wrong with your iterator? I quite liked it.

Comment: @Rawling: I was a bit embarrased posting such a long answer when it actually is a one liner. I removed that LINQ version and undeleted the answer to show only the iterator based approach.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The one liner approach of Rawling and Tim is very nice, but it has one little gotcha: `b` is iterated twice.
If that is a problem for you, you could use an iterator based approach. This can be created as an extension method:

```
public static bool IsContainedWithinInOrder<T>(this IEnumerable<T> values,
                                               IEnumerable<T> reference)
{
    using(var iterator = reference.GetEnumerator())
    {
        foreach(var item in values)
        {
            do
            {
                if(!iterator.MoveNext())
                    return false;
            } while(!Equals(iterator.Current, item));
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```

This would iterate both sequences only once and overall is more lightweight. You would call it like this:

```
b.IsContainedWithinInOrder(a);
```

Please forgive the name of the method...

Comment: Probably Daniel got enemies on StackOverflow... I will try the solution now.

Comment: Other than the lack of a `using`, I prefer this to mine as it doesn't depend on the opposite-to-how-it's-specified behaviour of `Intersect` and it doesn't bother storing anything it doesn't need to in memory. (And the double-iteration thing - I missed that.)

Comment: @Rawling: Indeed. I was just looking at the non-generic `IEnumerator` interface which is not disposable. What an odd design decision to make `IEnumerator<T>` disposable.

Answer (score 8):

You can use the following:

```
bool AContainsEverythingInBInTheSameOrder =
    a.Intersect(b).SequenceEquals(b);
```

`a.Intersect(b)` returns everything that is in both `a` and `b`, *in the same order in which it appears in `a`*.

Comment: won't work if lists contain duplicate values list a 1,2,3,1,2 list b 1,2,1

Comment: @eugeneK Yup, you're right there. (Didn't realise from your question that you could have duplicates.)

Comment: @eugeneK: You've got to admit that you never mentioned this requirement.

Comment: You right, haven't thought about that while writing the requirement.

Answer (score 6):

I assume that you have two lists and you want to check if the second list item have the same order as the same items in the first list.

Perhaps:

```
var allSameOrder = list1.Intersect(list2).SequenceEqual(list2);
```

[**Demo**](http://ideone.com/5HT6SS)

Comment: won't work if lists contain duplicate values list a 1,2,3,1,2 list b 1,2,1